# USPS not returning correct shipping for these 39 countries

Tags: usps

I am trying to processing international shipping requests through the USPS api.

I've found out that these 36 countries(?) do not return a shipping price.
In fact, I cannot seems to find a decent list of countries accepted by the USPS shipping api, there are always countries that return errors.

I tried https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search

Any ideas?

```
Object {country: "Åland Islands", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "American Samoa", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Antarctica", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Bouvet Island", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "British Indian Ocean Territory", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Côte d’Ivoire", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "French Southern Territories", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Holy See (Vatican City State)", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Iran, Islamic Republic of", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Lao People’s Democratic Republic", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Micronesia, Federated States of", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Moldova, Republic of", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Marshall Islands", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Northern Mariana Islands", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Palestinian Territory, Occupied", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Russian Federation", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Saint Barthélemy", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Saint Martin (French part)", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Somalia", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Syrian Arab Republic", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Tanzania, United Republic of", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Taiwan, Province of China", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "United States Minor Outlying Islands", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Virgin Islands, British", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Virgin Islands, U.S.", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Wallis and Futuna", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Western Sahara", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Yemen", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
products.js:195 Object {country: "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of", shipping_price: false, cart: Object}
```

I did another list of countries while removing the parenthesis and came up with this list of failed countries:

```
Countries Failed:
Åland Islands
American Samoa
Antarctica
Bosnia and Herzegovina
Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba
Bouvet Island
British Indian Ocean Territory
Cabo Verde
Cocos
Curaçao
Côte d'Ivoire
French Southern Territories
Falkland Islands (the) [Malvinas]
Guam
Heard Island and McDonald Islands
Holy See
Lao People's Democratic Republic
Marshall Islands
Micronesia
Palau
Northern Mariana Islands
Palestine, State of
Pitcairn
Puerto Rico
Russian Federation
Réunion
Saint Barthélemy
Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha
Somalia
South Sudan
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
Svalbard and Jan Mayen
Syrian Arab Republic
Tanzania, United Republic of
United States Minor Outlying Islands
United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland
Wallis and Futuna
Western Sahara*
United States of America
Yemen
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best list of accepted USPS locale names that I have found.

Many of the entries on your list can be found here with their correct wording.

Some (such as Svalbard) are not on the list.

Some are still broken even when using the name-form listed.

http://pe.usps.com/text/Imm/immctry.htm

**Update**
If you use the USPS names from the link above, the following will still fail (workarounds, if any, are included):

*Cote d’Ivoire:* replace "’" with space or use "Ivory Coast"

*Channel Islands (Jersey, Guernsey, Alderney, and Sark) (Great Britain and Northern Ireland):* remove comma after "Alderney", or use individual island names

*East Timor (Timor-Leste):* Use "East Timor" or "Timor-Leste"

*Guinea–Bissau:* Replace n dash with hyphen

*Ivory Coast (Cote d’Ivoire):* see above

*Korea, Democratic People’s Republic of (North Korea):* use "North Korea"

Also, some (Guatemala, Somalia, Syria, Yemen) will return errors explaining that there is no USPS service to that country.